# Unable to display static images and load CSS in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, pycharm

Using pycharm 2019.2.5, 
python 3.7, 
Django 2.2.5, 
I am creating a website by importing a template and creating apps for it through django, but I can't get any of the static files to work. When I run the dev server, none of the fonts/css/js/images display. Also I can't import google fonts from  my HTML file. I've read all the answers and I'm posting the pertinent data i'm aware of. This seems to be a fairly common question, and I've tried all their solutions. Let me know if you need more data.

```
YSMR       *edited to add. #This is my top-level project created in pycharm.
  YSMR     
    \blog
    \contact
    \schedule
    \sendemail
    \static
       \css   # I plan on adding namespacing for this later
       \fonts
       \js 
       images....    
    \templates
       \index.html
       additional templates...
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py
```

**index.html** below. I can view the file, but again, the embedded static files and font do not execute. The first several lines I've loaded below.

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>YSMR</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond:400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/animate.css" %}">
```

**Settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

ENV_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ENV_PATH, '/static/')  #I've tried to change 'static' to something else, but I get an 'unresolved reference' error when I do.

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "YSMR/static"), #I get an 'unresolved reference "static"' when I remove the YSMR
]
```

When I remove the YSMR from the STATICFILES_DIRS path, I get an "unresolved reference 'static'" warning

also, django.contrib.staticfiles is included in INSTALLED_APPS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using static as ```<link href="{% static 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond:400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i&display=swap' %}" rel="stylesheet">``` obviously this file is dynamic on web.

Comment: Change `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "YSMR/static")` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")`

Comment: i've tried removing the YSMR  in STATICFILES_DIRS, but I get an 'unresolved reference' error. Post updated to reflect that. @furkanayd that was just a URL included in the template. I'm sure that's clear to you. Less so me. Suggestion?

Comment: Well you are searching for a file in static directory which has a name 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond:400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i&display=swap' suggestion is removing the {% static ... %} part in your code

Comment: just for a quick troubleshooting check, can you please confirm if you have tried 'collectstatic' command ?

Comment: Replace
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "YSMR/static"), 
with 
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), 

because BASE_DIR is the path to YSMR

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean @furkanayd, thanks! Updated. I have run the collectstatic command. I established a project in pycharm called YSMR, then the original file path. I'm going to update it for clarity. I think it might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your settings as follows and try:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")
```

Also make sure that you added these lines to your main url file.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: please update your answer, as there is no "static_cdn" in mentioned directory. So replace "static_cdn" with "static"

Comment: when your run collectstatic command, if it is not there it will be created, actually it is not needed during development

Comment: ok, simple rules to follow https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
no need to mention static_cdn though

Comment: it is there for study purpose, so you can see what happens when you run a collectstatic command on local machine

Answer (score 0):

Change your settings as follows and try:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "app_name/static_root"), 
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "app_name/static")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
```

Also make sure that you added these lines to your main url file.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```